# Add selected if one of the array = my value

Tags: jquery, json

I received in JSON an array "transporteurs" and a simple POST value cmdTrp.

I want to add in the option selected="selected" if data.cmdTrp = value.id.

```
$.each(data.transporteurs, function (index, value) {
            $('#sous_commandes_transporteurselect').append($('<option/>', { 
            value: value.id,
            text : value.nom 
    }));
});
```

How can i do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: if my the value of cmdTrp (data.cmdTrp) equal 26 and if one of my array (value.id) contain 26 add option selected...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$.each(data.transporteurs, function (index, value) {
    $('#sous_commandes_transporteurselect').append($('<option/>', {
        value: value.id,
        text: value.nom
    }).prop('selected', data.cmdTrp == value.id));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y3Xgd/)

---

As @Royi said

```
$.each(data.transporteurs, function (index, value) {
    $('#sous_commandes_transporteurselect').append($('<option/>', {
        value: value.id,
        text: value.nom,
        selected: data.cmdTrp == value.id
    }));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y3Xgd/2/)

Comment: Also this `selected:data.cmdTrp == value.id` would work. (+1)